Static table height, dynamic rows height and min-height
What I'm trying to achieve is to have a table with a static height, but table rows with a dynamic height and min-height.
For example, I have a table with 5 rows, each row has a different amount of data. If a row is empty and all the others are full, I want the empty one to shrink to a specified min-height, while the others stretch as much as they need (the table will be scrollable if it exceeds its height, so overflow: auto). But if the table is fully empty, I want it to keep its static height while having all the table rows stretched out so it fits nicely.
Now, I am aware the you can't use min-height in table cells, I'm just looking for something that has the same effect.
This is what I'm currently doing.
This is what I'm trying to achieve.
(I'll only have 1 table, there's 3 here to showcase multiple scenarios)


table {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  float: left;
  table-layout: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin: 20px;
}

thead tr {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

table thead th {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 20px;
}

table thead tr th:nth-child(1){
  max-width: 15%;
  width: 15%;
}
table thead tr th:nth-child(2){
  max-width: 15%;
  width: 15%;
}
table thead tr th:nth-child(3){
  max-width: 20%;
  width: 20%;
}
table thead tr th:nth-child(4){
  max-width: 20%;
  width: 20%;
}

table td {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  height: 20px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>dynamic row height and min height</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Info</th>
          <th>Descripion</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>001</div>
            <div>002</div>
            <div>003</div>
            <div>004</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div>1N</div>
            <div>2N</div>
            <div>3N</div>
            <div>4N</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div>1info</div>
            <div>2info</div>
            <div>3info</div>
            <div>4info</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div>1desc</div>
            <div>2desc</div>
            <div>3desc</div>
            <div>4desc</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>005</div>
            <div>006</div>
            </td>
          <td>
            <div>5N</div>
            <div>6N</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div>5info</div>
            <div>6info</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div>5desc</div>
            <div>6desc</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>007</div>
            <div>008</div>
            <div>009</div>
            <div>010</div>
            <div>011</div>
            <div>012</div>
            <div>013</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div>7N</div>
            <div>8N</div>
            <div>9N</div>
            <div>10N</div>
            <div>11N</div>
            <div>12N</div>
            <div>13N</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div>7info</div>
            <div>8info</div>
            <div>9info</div>
            <div>10info</div>
            <div>11info</div>
            <div>12info</div>
            <div>13info</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div>7desc</div>
            <div>8desc</div>
            <div>9desc</div>
            <div>10desc</div>
            <div>11desc</div>
            <div>12desc</div>
            <div>13desc</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>014</div>
            <div>015</div>
            <div>016</div>
            <div>017</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div>14N</div>
            <div>15N</div>
            <div>16N</div>
            <div>17N</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div>14info</div>
            <div>15info</div>
            <div>16info</div>
            <div>17info</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div>14desc</div>
            <div>15desc</div>
            <div>16desc</div>
            <div>17desc</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Info</th>
          <th>Descripion</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>001</div>
            <div>002</div>
            <div>003</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div>1N</div>
            <div>2N</div>
            <div>3N</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div>1info</div>
            <div>2info</div>
            <div>3info</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div>1desc</div>
            <div>2desc</div>
            <div>3desc</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div>007</div>
            <div>008</div>
            <div>009</div>
            <div>010</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div>7N</div>
            <div>8N</div>
            <div>9N</div>
            <div>10N</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div>7info</div>
            <div>8info</div>
            <div>9info</div>
            <div>10info</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div>7desc</div>
            <div>8desc</div>
            <div>9desc</div>
            <div>10desc</div
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Info</th>
          <th>Descripion</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>



Tried using a wrapper, as that would supposedly allow me to set min-height and height, but that resulted in basically the same thing I have now.
I've also tried playing around with heights, overflows and other css attributes in different tags, but the best result I managed to get is the code shown in the question.
EDIT: A wrapper (for the entire table) did in fact work. I don't know what I did wrong the first few times I tried, but I wrapped the whole table in a div, give it the required width/height and overflow: auto, then changed the table's display to table, which resulted in what I needed.
Snippet here: https://jsfiddle.net/3u0x84t2/9/

How would using a wrapper around the individual cell contents not be working? https://jsfiddle.net/4xhtc18d/ - wrapper elements added via JS there, but the result is what you want, no?

Maybe have a look at grid as an alternative as you have much more control over the size of cells?

@CBroe Unfortunately that doesn't do what I want it to. It acts the same as what I currently have, aka it leaves the gap at the bottom when the table is empty and the empty table rows don't shrink when others extend.

@Adam I was wondering if there's a way to do this while maintaining the table structure. I'll resort to that if I can't manage to find a solution. :)

If you just set the td height to whatever minimum value you want the table cell will shrink down to that size if it's empty? Will that not work?

@Adam look at the snippets please. That's what I am doing right now, but not what I want. What I want it to do is stretch out if it's empty, but shrink when other rows are being stretched out due to them having "too much" data. Either way, I found a solution, so I'll edit the post now. Thank you anyway :)

That's great! Look forward to seeing the result. Glad you got it sorted.

@Adam sorry for the delay - edited the post with a solution :)
